# MySQL: ERROR 1006 (HY000) Can't create database (errno: 26469527)

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm running a Homebrew install of MySQL 5.7.14 on my Mac, El Capitan 10.11.6 and I can't create databases when logged in with my 'root' user. I get the error,

MySQL: ERROR 1006 (HY000) Can't create database 'db_name' (errno: 26469527)

I don't believe that this is the same as other common errors I've read about with creating databases, which are the result of a lack of permissions.  I ran SHOW GRANTS 'root'; and root seems to have full permissions.

I'm new to sql so I apologize if this is an easy fix that I just missed.

If any other information would be helpful let me know.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using

- Mac OS Sierra 10.12.2
- MySQL 5.7.16 installed through brew.

I had a similar issue. What I didn't notice was after `brew install mysql` you need to

1. Reboot the computer
2. run `mysql_secure_installation`

After I did the above I was able to setup a user with password and create database without issues. I tried some of the other suggestions and change the mysql data directory's permission but it didn't work. Running `mysql_secure_installation` also failed without rebooting the system first. I'm sure there are probably fixes that doesn't require the reboot, but I didn't spend time digging further.

Comment: Using Mac OS High Sierra 10.13. This worked for me. Thanks

Comment: It works. thanks. But I wonder why it happened? I usually create the database without problem.

Comment: who would have thought! Once again a restart comes to rescue even after brew install. Blew my mind.. No need of secure installation though. :)
Thanks yuklai :)

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the permissions or ownership of your MySQL data directory. Likely, the data directory is owned by root but the MySQL process is running under the user mysql.

To find out where your data directory is located, from shell/console, type in:

```
 mysqladmin variables | grep datadir
```

The directory will be shown on the right hand side.  Lets say the directory is /var/lib/mysql, then, from the shell/console, type in:

```
 chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

That's assuming that your MySQL process is running as the user mysql.

Comment: mysqladmin variables gives me an access denied error for my user account.  When I try to give access to my user account ('firstlastname'@'localhost') using GRANT SELECT in mysql while running the process as root user, I get a permission denied error.

Answer (score 3):

Check if your disk is full.

```
df -h
```

Answer (score 2):

If you encounter below error during database creation, check this:

```
mysql> create database harrypotter;
ERROR 1006 (HY000): Can't create database 'databasename' (errno: 15430336)
```

1. Check you system storage (In my case, it was 100% used):

   `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            476M     0  476M   0% /dev
tmpfs            98M  3.3M   95M   4% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.7G  7.7G     0 100% /
tmpfs           490M     0  490M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           490M     0  490M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       32M   32M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11036
/dev/loop1       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1988
/dev/loop2       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1997
/dev/loop3       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11588
/dev/loop4       34M   34M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
tmpfs            98M     0   98M   0% /run/user/1000
```

- It worked for me by freeing some space :)